# mod_ruid2 not working with apache 2.4.18

Tags: apache, cpanel, bugs, whm

I thought I did good service to my server by upgrading everything to php 5.6, and apache 2.4.18 through the easyapache interface, but now, apache won't start.

```
! Executing custom hook '/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/posteasyapache' !!
httpd: Syntax error on line 34 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ruid2.so into server: /usr/local/apache/modules mod_ruid2.so: undefined symbol: unixd_config
!! Done executing '/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/posteasyapache' !!
!! '/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/posteasyapache 3.32.9 9999 2.4.18 0,5.6.17' failed with exit code '256' !!
!! Verbose logfile is at '/usr/local/cpanel/logs/easy/apache/build.1453525845' !!
```

I'm curious if there is a known workaround to this other than to resort to being stuck with apache 2.2. I thought of trying apache 2.4 because there was mentioning that the proxy modules would run faster, but at the state things are, it seems I can't use 2.4 without trouble.

Anyone have any advice on how to easily solve this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is appears to be about system administration and would be better suited to ServerFault.